# Required or not depending on one field - Embedded forms Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, symfony

I'm doing a Forum bundle where you can add (or not) a vote to your subject.
The problem is that the embedded form (the question and the answers) has to be required only if a boolean is true.

I first tried some solutions I found here and there on the internet but nothing worked.
Then I created 2 forms, one with a vote, another without and I created a little switch with some JQuery.

The problem is that when I want to create a subject and only fill one form, HTML5 tells me there are fields required I didn't fill in the other form, it doesn't only send the form I'm trying to submit, it apparently submits both.

Do you know why and how I could solve this, or maybe a simpler technique to dynamically define if a field is required or not ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions listed here, that allow you to dynamically modify forms based on submitted data?  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

Comment: The point is that i don't submit anything before creating the form. :(
I want the whole form to be filled and submitted at the same time.

Comment: I'm not understanding - do you set the vote true/false flag when creating your own post?  Or is it on like, every reply?  I guess I'm not understanding the flow you are attempting.

Comment: I send in one form:
*The true/false flag
*The title + the content
*And the Vote if true is checked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem, so here is it:

- I add the **FormType** of the embedded form as **required false**
- I add a **PRE_SUBMIT** that check if the user wants to add a vote
- If not I **delete the data** (the question) that is sent to my controller

In fact it was the Question that created a problem because it is OneToOne associated with my subject, which means I can't add the option allow_delete (as I do for the answers).
Here was my error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship '...' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: ... To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement '...' to get a clue.

For those who would like to see how i add the event here is a simple code ([highly inspired from the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html)):

In the **buildForm method**:

```
->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'))
```

Then you create **another method**:

```
public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    if($data['vote'])
    {
    }
    else
    {
        unset($data['question']);
        $event->setData($data);
    }
}
```